# Why my async/await method is waiting for another async method only if response is decostructed

Tags: javascript, async-await

I just try to understand what is happening - why my async method is waiting for another async method only if the response is deconstructed?

So I have some example code:

*Dummy promise*

```
const psedoRequest = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "resolved"));
}
```

*Dummy method which is calling promise*

```
const methodRequest = async() => {
  let response = "";
  let error = "";

  try {
    response = await psedoRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }

  return { response, error };
}
```

*Actual methods*

```
const invalidMainMethod = async() => {

  const results = await methodRequest().response;
  console.log('Invalid', results)
  // the same would be with:
  // const response = await methodRequest().response; 
  // console.log('Invalid', response );
}

const validMainMethod = async() => {
  let results = ""

  const { response } = await methodRequest();
  results = response;
  console.log('Valid', results);
}
```

Console log returns:

```
Invalid undefined
Valid resolved
```

Why deconstructing actually works in that case - so it's waiting for a response while accessing directly `.response` is not?
I thought that deconstructing is some syntactic sugar.

Comment: because `await methodRequest().response` is equivalent to `await (methodRequest().response)` but you would actually need `(await methodRequest()).response`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ambiguous (to humans) and doesn't mean what you think it means:

```
await methodRequest().response
```

Are you awaiting `methodRequest()`?  Or are you awaiting the `response` property from what `methodRequest()` returns?

Be explicit:

```
const results = (await methodRequest()).response;
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> const results = await methodRequest().response;
> ```

Property accessing has higher precedence than `await` so this:

1. Calls `methodRequest`
2. Gets a promise object
3. Reads `response` (which is `undefined`) from the promise
4. `await`s `undefined` (which isn't a promise so has no significant effect)
5. Assigns `undefined` to `results`

Later the promise resolves.

You could get the desired effect by using parentheses to override precedence:

```
const results = (await methodRequest()).response;
```

---

> ```
> const { response } = await methodRequest();
> ```

`await` has higher precedence than `=` so it `await`s the promise first **then** assigns and deconstruction is done as part of assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I see David was faster, but since I have already written my response here it is anyways:

The simple difference here is the syntax:

```js
const response = await methodRequest().response;
```

This snippet awaits `methodRequest().response`
What you are expecting it to do is to await `methodRequest()` and then get the response.

```js
const { response } = await methodRequest();
```

This awaits `methodRequest()` and then takes the response from it like this:

```js
const response = (await methodRequest()).response
```